# Why people wouldn't just use the maximum available clock in microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, clock, stm32

The topic is rather straight forward and I admit i wasn't able to find much on google.

Recently i started to code on STM32 and for a person that is coming from PC-related application, setting all the clocks was rather new.

I was wondering why a developer would want to discard/avoid maximum clock and in which condition?
Say that a microcontroller could work at 168Mhz, why should i choose 84Mhz?

Is it mainly related to power consumption? Are there any other reason?

Why the STM32 team (and microchip as well i guess) took the hassle of setting up a really nice UI on STM32CubeMX to select different combination?
Why should i use an external oscillator directly rather than the PLL path if i can achieve higher working frequency?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/232941/when-would-be-occasions-to-use-a-lower-clock-given-that-high-speed-would-always

Comment: Thank you, a partial answer is there.

Comment: Why? For the same reason people don't drive their cars at maximum speed most of the time.

Comment: Wow that is a really good answer @tonypdmtr sums it up very nicely.

Comment: There are also thermal considerations to take into account for some applications.
Higher frequencies usually mean higher temperatures.
Maybe someone with more knowledge could elaborate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it mainly related to power consumption?

Yes, mainly. Lower frequency means lower consumption.

One could also save power by doing the work fast, then putting the cpu to sleep, thus improving average consumption, but the power supply might not like the variable load, and exact timekeeping would be rather difficult.

> Are there any other reason?

Yes. Some peripherals don't work above certain frequencies. An example: the STM32F429 core can run at 180 MHz, but then there is no way to generate 48 MHz for USB. In order to use USB, the core must run at 168 MHz.

> Why should i use an external oscillator directly rather than the PLL path if i can achieve higher working frequency?

An external oscillator has a much higher accuracy than an internal one, and it may take too long for a PLL to stabilize when waking up from standby. It depends on the application requirements.

Comment: "it may take too long" could you quantify it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291935/hal-rcc-oscconfig-takes-too-long-appx-170-%CE%BCs-i-need-it-to-be-50-%CE%BCs-when-waki/40301301#40301301

Answer (score 5):

Power is probably the main reason. But there may be various other reasons that a specific clock speed is used such as:

EMC emmissions.

Avoiding harmonics which interfere with sensitive analogue electronics.

Driving timers / clocks / ADCs etc that are required to be run at a very specific frequency as part of the design (For example I worked on a processor that run at 120MHz, however in order to get the exact required ADC sampling we had to run at something like 119.4MHz).

You might want to use an external oscillator if you intend to use the clock elsewhere on the board. Also you might want to use a very accurate crystal, or maybe not want to wait for the PLL to lock.

There are lots of reasons. However if you are doing something straight forward and don't care about power consumption or noise then running at max speed with the PLL is probably the best place to start in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Power is the obvious one, and as it has been touched on in other answers but not directly.  Performance.  Faster clock does not mean faster code.  ST has this magic cachy thing in front of the flash in addition to a real-ish cache in front of the flash (and disabled the arm cache it appears on the cortex-m4's I have tried).  But in general the flash is your bottleneck, if as you see on a number of other vendor parts and sometimes ST, you have to keep adding wait states as you increase the system clock.  So say at 16Mhz no wait states, at 32, one, 48 two and so on, depends on the system, you are dancing around the speed limit of the flash, making the processor sit around extra clocks while it waits for instructions to come in.  And even on an st but easier to see on others, that directly affects your performance, you want to be perhaps right at the frequency where you go from zero to one wait states to maximize what you can feed the cpu.

Some designs the flash is already at half speed of the cpu/system clock where sram generally tracks and can cover the full range, so take the same code at zero wait states and run from flash then run from ram, on some number of MCUs the same machine code runs half speed on flash as it does on sram.  some it is one to one and then when you add a wait state flash is half speed vs ram, and so on.

Peripherals have the same problem as mentioned.  You may have to use a prescaler on the peripheral clock, so now reading a gpio pin that at 24mhz might have taken one clock at 80mhz may take three or four clocks.

PLLs are analog and jittery, they dont necessarily "lose" any clock cycles, but are worse as far as jitter as the oscillator which itself has a spec on jitter and accuracy as well as temperature affects.  So the internal RC is the worst quality clock, direct from the oscillator bypassing the PLL is the best, then multiplying with the PLL will add jitter, but will allow you to go faster.

Back to power.  The battery in your remote control on your TV might last a year or so (infra red, the bluetooth ones are days or weeks), they run the lowest clock rate they can to barely do the job and stay off as much as possible or in low power state.  If they were to hop up to 120Mhz when they were awake and the battery now lasts weeks or half a year, vs a year, for no real benefit other than it is really cool to run at full speed.  That doesnt make much sense.  We heavily rely on battery based products now, if the microcontroller in the bluetooth module on your phone ran at its fully rated pll speed, and the microcontroller in your wifi module in your phone, and the one that drives the display, etc, all ran at max speed, your phone might not last even a day on one full charge.  Nothing was gained by running faster, but something was lost.

For hobbies and stuff plugged into the wall, burn whatever power you want, but a noticable percentage of the mcu market is about price and power, chips that are screened to a higher speed cost more, lower speed parts, in some cases are just the chips that failed the higher screen, and cost less.  tighter smaller code uses less flash you can buy a smaller/cheaper part, your clock can run slower because it takes fewer instructions to do the same thing than a possibly sloppy program and/or bad choice in programming languages, bigger part, lower yield both add to cost.  then lowering the clock as low as you can go to keep your tightly written code to just barely meet timing uses the least amount of power ideally (As well as turning off or not turning on peripherals you are not using and prescaling the ones that are on even slower).

For cost and power you want the slowest clock you can tolerate with the smallest binary that is also tight and efficient so that you can just barely make timing.  That is your ideal goal.  But if you plan for field upgrades then you need to leave some margin for slower/larger code to be part of the upgrade and not have a dramatic effect on power consumption.